# RESTEASY003720: path param has not been provided while constructing ResteasyClient

Tags: resteasy

I see this error while running my tests when migrating from Resteasy jaxrs 3 to Resteasy client 4: (`org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient`)

```
RESTEASY003720: path param xxxx has not been provided while constructing
```

I set the target URL to be "localhost:8080". How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that target URL must include the scheme; when I change it to `http://localhost:8080` the error disappears.

Comment: It has to include the schema so that it knows how to connect.

Comment: Yes I was naive :)